# Ensuring data integrity of mysqldump <-> rsync

Tags: backup, mysql, rsync

I use rsync to back up the files on my server, and mysqldump to back up my database.  Here's my concern:

A mysqldump on my database takes about 30 seconds.  I have a table called photos that stores info about the images a user has uploaded, including the path to the file.  I am worried about what will happen when photos are uploaded or deleted during the 30 seconds it takes to complete the mysqldump.  If that happened and I were then to restore the rsync'd files and the mysqldump data, I could then be looking at a database that contains rows pointing to deleted photos, or missing rows for photos that were successfully uploaded.

How can I make sure the mysqldump exactly matches the rsync?

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) to block any write activity from the tables you're backing up. Then unlock them once your `mysqldump` is finished.

Comment: Locking the tables for the duration of the mysqldump is not sufficient - you also need to keep them locked while the rsync is running. Otherwise, if e.g. the rsync follows the dump, files may get deleted on disk that the dump claims should be there; yet those files don't end up in the rsync.

Comment: So - if the tables are locked and a user uploads a file, the INSERT query to create the record will proceed once the tables are unlocked?  Is it bad if the query has to wait for 30+ seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is simple, just run rsync AFTER you complete mysqldump :) This way at worst you will have a couple NEW files that are not in the db dump, but you will not have inconsistent db entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could MD5 the resulting mysqldump (on the server) and the transfered (locally) by rsync, then compare the two hashes to ensure they match.
Another alternative, is to set mysqldump on a version controlled file (with git or svn or your favorite vcs). The advantage with git, for example, is that you could easily setup some post-commit hooks to push the changes to a remote server, and the upload would be just the differences between versions, not the entire dump. This way you could think in decreasing the backup period.